# Enable WAP Push to iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, push

I'm trying to send a [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol) push to an iPhone 4 over an SMS bearer. This is simply an SMS with a WAP link in the UDH. I'm using an SMS gateway, and all indications are that it was delivered to the carrier (AT&T) successfully, but no message appears on the device, and no SI (Service Indication) pops up. An identical message sent to a Blackberry (also on AT&T) works as expected.

Is there a setting on the iPhone to control this? Do iPhones just not support this type of message?

Confession: I am not an iPhone user, but I do have access to one for testing purposes.

Comment: Would somebody please explain the rationale for migrating this from Apple to SO? It's not really a programming issue, rather settings/capabilities of the iPhone device.

Answer (score 0):

The iphone cannot use wap push messages

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1157201?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: The article is from 2007. One of the arguments is that, like MMS, you can't send WAP-SMS. This however might not still be the case, as MMS was implemented in iOS2/3.